# Writing a square as a sum of three non-zero squares in geometric progression

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $k$ be a given positive integer. I want to solve the following system of Diophantine equations: $$\begin{cases} a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = k^2 \\ b^2 = ac \end{cases}$$
where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ are non-zero.

There is an OEIS sequence for the numbers which are sums of three non-zero squares, but I don't know of any general expression (some squares, such as 25, are not there).

I know, by substituting the second equation into the first, that $k = m^2 + n^2 + mn$, $a = m^2 - n^2$ and $c = 2mn + n^2$, where $m, n$ are coprime integers, but I don't really know how to use this, since plugging this back into the second equation yields a very complicated looking one (namely, when is the product a square?)

I'm not used to solving Diophantine equations (much less systems of them), but I have tried direct computation and seriously believe that there is no solution.

Are there any hints or techniques for solving this type of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DietrichBurde As I stated in the question, I genuinely believe there is none - for any k, actually - but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: $(2a+c)^2+3c^2=(2k)^2$ has no solution?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756405/to-prove-that-as-i-believe-a-particular-pair-of-diophantine-equations-has-no-s?noredirect=1). Your first equation is also $a^2+ac+c^2=k^2$. They write $d^2$ for $k^2$. You can do a very similar proof. You can also use the parametric solutions given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445717/how-to-solve-the-diophantine-equation-x2xyy2-r2-x-y-r-in-bbb-z?noredirect=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! There is just one thing - how do I transform my cubic into an elliptic curve? I ask because it is not monic. Is there a standard reference I can look up?

Comment: @BobDobbs Oh, I see! I can apply the Pythagorean solution to that case. Maybe a naive question, but are they going to yield all the primitive solutions in this case?

Comment: Please provide the link to the OEIS sequence.

Comment: @user25406 Sure: https://oeis.org/A000408

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we may demand $ \gcd(a,b,c) = 1$   by dividing through by any common factor. This works because of homogeneity.

Next, $ac=b^2$  implies that
$$  a = x^2, \; \; b = xy, \; \; c = y^2   $$

At this point you have
$$  x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 = k^2 $$
with $\gcd(x,y) = 1.$     This is the result labelled (7') on page 19 of Mordell, *Diophantine Equations*.  There are only trivial solutions. The proof is about a page,  on pages 19 and 20. Worth looking up and going through it in detail. It is just taking the "smallest"  positive solution  and showing a contradiction. No elliptic curves.

Comment: Can't we prove by rearranging to $(x^2+y^2)^2=k^2+(xy)^2$, so by the Pythagorean triple parameters we have $\{k,xy\}=\{2xy, x^2-y^2\}$. Obviously $xy \ne 2xy$, so $k=2xy$. But then we get $(x^2+y^2)^2=5(xy)^2$, which is clearly impossible if $(x,y)=0$, since $5$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: @EricSnyder   My first impression is that we need not have both $x,y$   odd.  Suppose we have $x$  odd and $y$  even. Then $k$  is odd  while $xy$ is even. This time we need alternate coprime parameters $p,q$    with $p^2 + q^2 = x^2 + y^2$  which must now be composite, then $k = p^2 - q^2$    while $xy = 2pq.$  A small example could have $x^2 + y^2 = 65$ with $x=1$ and $y=8.$   Please let me know what you think. $ \hspace{3mm}$

Comment: Argh, I hadn't even considered the case where $x^2+y^2 = p^2+q^2$ for two pairs of integers. Yeah, that kills that method of proof. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to  Will Jagy's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445717/how-to-solve-the-diophantine-equation-x2xyy2-r2-x-y-r-in-bbb-z?noredirect=1), a parametric solution of $a^2+ ac +c^2=k^2$ is given as follows.
$(a,c)=(u^2-v^2,2uv+v^2)$.
Hence we get $b^2=2vu^3+v^2u^2-2v^3u-v^4$.
Above equation can be transformed to an elliptic curve below where $X=2u/v$ .
$$Y^2 = X^3+X^2-4X-4$$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/48/a/4), this elliptic curve has rank $0$ and has three integer solutions $(X,Y)=(-2, 0), (-1, 0), (2, 0)$.
Hence the problem has no positive integer solution.